# knockoutjs containerless if around <tr> and </tr>

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to build a table as follows, but I get "Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if: cellIsStartOfRow".

Am I doing it wrong?

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: MyDocs">
        <!-- ko if: cellIsStartOfRow --> 
            <tr class="docsRow">
        <!-- /ko -->  
                <td>

                      <!-- There is more databinding in here - a div containing a textarea and also containing a hyperlink surrounding an image.  I think the contents are irrelevant to my question, but I can post if someone disagrees.-->  

                </td> 

        <!-- ko if: cellIsEndOfRow --> 
            </ tr>
        <!-- /ko --> 

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the JS for the viewmodel.  The contents of the td above are somewhat simplified, because I thought it was fairly irrelevant what was in there.  I call the functions from other js on my page.  The viewmodel itself is assigned to a variable that is declared on the page.

```
Type.registerNamespace("HpDocs");


HpDocs.DocsVM = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);


    // add additional properties to each document for presentation
    // purposes
    for (i = 0; i < this.MyDocs().length; i++) {
        var myDoc = this.MyDocs()[i];
        myDoc.docObjectId = "docObject" + myDoc.Id();
        myDoc.textareaId = "ucHpDocs" + "_txta";

        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = true;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = false;
        } else if (i % 5 == 5) {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = false;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = true;
        } else {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = false;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = false;
        }
    }
};

HpDocs.DocsVM.prototype = {
//    cellIsStartOfRow: function(){
//        return true;
//    },
    getDocs: function (filter) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: getMethodUrl("GetDocs"),
            data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
            success: function (response) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d, {}, self.MyDocs);
            }
        })
    }
};

HpDocs.dbGetDocs = function (filter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getMethodUrl("DbGetDocs"),
        data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
        success: function (response) {

            myDocsViewModel = new HpDocs.DocsVM({
                MyDocs: ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)
            });

            var bindingScope = $("#divMyDocs")[0];
            ko.applyBindings(myDocsViewModel, bindingScope);

            $(".DocsUpdateProgress").addClass("invisible");
        }
    })
};


HpDocs.getPreferredTab = function () {
    var tabPref = $("[id$='hidDocTabPreference']").html();
    return tabPref;
};

HpDocs.showProgress = function () {
    $(".DocsUpdateProgress").removeClass("invisible");
};
HpDocs.hideProgress = function () {
    $(".DocsUpdateProgress").addClass("invisible");
};



//register the class
HpDocs.DocsVM.registerClass('HpDocs.DocsVM', null, Sys.IDisposable);


// notify ajax that the script is now loaded.
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

#### ANSWER

I refactored my model:  instead of having MyDocs contain a list of objects, I now have it containing a property called Rows which in turn contains a property called Documents.  Then, I can just do the following:

```
<table id="tblMyDocs">
                <tbody data-bind="foreach:  MyDocs.Rows">

                        <tr data-bind="foreach: Documents">
                                  <td>
                                          <!-- in here i present each document by databinding to the Model's properties -->
                                  <td>
                        </tr>
                 </tbody>
</table>
```

and of course the viewmodel is much easier, since the model is now organized in rows:

```
HpDocs.DocsVM = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

HpDocs.DocsVM.prototype = {
    getDocs: function (filter) {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: getMethodUrl("GetDocs"),
            data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
            success: function (response) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d, {}, self.MyDocs);
            }
        })
    }
};

HpDocs.dbGetDocs = function (filter) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getMethodUrl("DbGetDocs"),
        data: "{'filter': " + filter + "}",
        success: function (response) {

            myDocsViewModel = new HpDocs.DocsVM({
                MyDocs: ko.mapping.fromJS(response.d)
            });

            var bindingScope = $("#divMyDocs")[0];
            ko.applyBindings(myDocsViewModel, bindingScope);

            HpDocs.hideProgress();
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript? Or Update this fiddle with your code and javascript to expose the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/LKS5b/

Comment: I believe there is a better way to resolve this using mvvm patterns that will make your life easier once I see your JS :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - JS added to original question.

Comment: Where is the JS? I'm not seeing it, just the HTML (UPDATE: I think it was cached, because I just updated again and now see it)

Comment: Sorry, my fault... I added the comment before the JS.  Also, I still had 'someArray' as foreach databinding - corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding formatting logic to your js like below:

```
// add additional properties to each document for presentation
    // purposes
    for (i = 0; i < this.MyDocs().length; i++) {
        var myDoc = this.MyDocs()[i];
        myDoc.docObjectId = "docObject" + myDoc.Id();
        myDoc.textareaId = "ucHpDocs" + "_txta";

        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = true;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = false;
        } else if (i % 5 == 5) {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = false;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = true;
        } else {
            myDoc.cellIsStartOfRow = false;
            myDoc.cellIsEndOfRow = false;
        }
```

I would suggest creating a separate viewmodel for row of data. Since you didn't provide any json data, I wasn't able to solve it 100%, but hopefully this gets you in the right direction. Here is the jsfiddle I was working off of: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/GcSAn/2/

**View**

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: someArray">
            <tr class="docsRow" data-bind="foreach:docRows">
                <td>
                    <div data-bind="attr:  {id: objectId}">
                       <a data-bind="attr: {href: someUrl}">
                          <img data-bind="attr: {src: IconPath, alt: Tooltip}"/>
                       </a> 
                       <br/>
                       <textarea runat="server" readonly="readonly" data-bind="html: DisplayName"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </td> 
            </ tr>

   </tbody>
</table>​​​​​
```

**Javascript**

```
HpDocs.RowVM = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

}

HpDocs.DocsVM = function(data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.docRows = ko.observableArray();

    // add additional properties to each document for presentation
    // purposes
    for (i = 0; i < this.MyDocs().length; i++) {
        var myDoc = this.MyDocs()[i];
        myDoc.docObjectId = "docObject" + myDoc.Id();
        myDoc.textareaId = "ucHpDocs" + "_txta";

        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            // create new RowVM and start adding DocsVM to it
        } else if (i % 5 == 5) {
            // push the RowVM to this.docRows populated with cells
        } else {
            // add the myDoc to the current RowVM you are working with
        }
    }
};
```

**UPDATED - Links to knockout talk on how to create proper mvvm**

Slides and examples: http://bit.ly/FamilyFeudSlides

Code: https://github.com/jasonmore/familyfeud

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking I might have to do this but wasn't sure how to go about it.  I'll mark as answered after I change my code (and once StackOverflow lets me - I think I have to wait six hours or something).  I'm still curious about the original problem though.  Is that a limitation of the <!-- ko if  --> stuff?  Maybe it doesn't support separate ifs around some types of open/close tags?

Comment: My thoughts on the <!-- ko if --> stuff is that makes it easier to hack things in, vs following the proper mvvm convention. The good thing about mvvm is there is really one way to accomplish the goal, and the bad thing is there is really only one way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: If it were me, I would refactor the data coming from the server so the rows make sense with what is being displayed in the columns. Then create proper models which represent that data. Gone are the days of jquery hacking :-)  I just gave a talk on knockout, and the slides and code might help you.

Slides and examples: http://bit.ly/FamilyFeudSlides

Code: https://github.com/jasonmore/familyfeud

Comment: After messing about for a while with the viewmodel, I think I will refactor the model as you suggest. Seems easier.

Comment: Sure enough, it's a lot easier now.  See end of original post for my final code.  (I am not permitted to add an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was here:

```
<!-- ko if: cellIsStartOfRow --> 
   <tr class="docsRow">
<!-- /ko -->
```

you have to have both open and close tags inside the if, so..

```
<!-- ko if: cellIsStartOfRow --> 
   <tr class="docsRow">
   ... 
   </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```